# python asyncio - cleanup event loop on ctrl+c? and close() vs stop()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, event-loop

Code:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# add tasks to the loop
# ...

# and then run the loop
try:
   loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   print(loop)
   # Here I need to run a cleanup, I still need to use the event loop
   # Can I still use the event loop here? like:
   loop.run_until_complete(some_cleanup_coro())
```

1. when I print the event loop in the `except` block, I see the output: `WindowsSelectorEventLoop`, with `closed=False`, `running=False.`
   Does it means I can't use the event loop in the `except` block? then how can I run a cleanup coroutine?

The `run_until_complete` call hangs and not running. So pressing <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> does not exit and I have to close the terminal itself.

2. What's the difference between `loop.close()` and `loop.stop()`, and should I call these? The docs say nothing about `loop.stop()`.

My `cleanup_coro()` does mostly `asyncio.open_connection(..)` and just sends and receives one message. (From what I see, the message is not sent at all).

Answer (score 3):

> Does it means I can't use the event loop in the `except` block?

You can keep using the event loop until it closes.

> So pressing <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> does not exit and I have to close the terminal itself.

Why <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> doesn't work is because something keep running, so it did not give the loop a chance to accept the signal (<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>). Just like:

```
import asyncio

async def go():
    await asyncio.sleep(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(go())
```

According to your last edit, I think there is a line of code blocking you before you send the message. But for me to tell you what it is, you would need to post your `cleanup_coro()` content. Or you can use `print()` to mark what happens where (i.e. which line of code is *pending*).

> What's the difference between `loop.close()` and `loop.stop()`, and should I call these? The docs says nothing about `loop.stop()`.

You can imagine that `loop.close()` and `loop.stop()` are similar to "next song" and "stop this song". If you don't need "this song", so play the "next one". If you want to continue the task later, use `stop`. However, when you don't need the running task at all, you can `close` the loop. Note: If any tasks is running you must stop before closing.

Comment: What do you mean by a cycle which never stops? I can't see an infinite loop

Comment: not exactly, my cleanup uses a socket. I've updated the question

Comment: In my example,   _cls refers itself. _cls can finish , but the premise is _cls finished. It became a impossible mission.

Comment: Could you provide more details about cleanup_coro()? Because open connection and read/send message will not occur this. Unless something is blocking you.

Answer (score 1):

In your except block, the loop is no longer running, but not closed, so you can start it again (`loop.run*`). This state occurs when something calls `loop.stop`. asyncio will do this for you in the case of exceptions that bubble up through the code that started the loop. You can start and stop a loop as often as you’d like.

Without knowing what `some_cleanup_coroutine` does, or what other coroutines are still schedule with the event loop, it’s hard to say when your code is getting hung.

Calling `loop.close` will prevent you from starting it again. You’d need to get a new loop (`asyncio.new_event_loop`) if you want to do more work.

Comment: My cleanup just opens an asyncio connection and send a message